# GcmNetworkManager periodic task not being triggered on some devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcm-network-manager

I am using `GcmNetworkManager` to run periodic sync tasks to push data to my server.
However, after shipping the app I noticed that in some of the phones the periodic task is never called.
I have already debugged the app is some of those phone and see nothing unusual, there isn't any error or log when I schedule the task, but they simply are never called.

Most of my users have [Infinix](http://infinixmobility.com/) phones.

Any ideas of what could be the root cause of this?

Here is the code in which I schedule the task:

```
  Task task = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setService(mClazz)
            .setPeriod(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(period))
            .setFlex(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(period / 5))
            .setTag(TAG_SYNC)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .build();

    mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
```

Comment: Please share your code wherein `GcmNetworkManager` was used.

Comment: Edited question to include code sample

Answer (score 0):

In using [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager) class,

> To receive the notification from the scheduler that a task is ready to be executed, your client app must implement a `GcmTaskService` and filter on the action [`SERVICE_ACTION_EXECUTE_TASK`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService#SERVICE_ACTION_EXECUTE_TASK).

Likewise, based from [GcmTaskService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService), your implementation should call `super.onStartCommand()`, otherwise your task will not be started correctly.

In addition to that, solution given in this SO post - [GCM Network Manager - Periodic Task not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396499/gcm-network-manager-periodic-task-not-firing/32316468) might also help.

Happy coding!